# Problem starting a RubyonRails application on Media Temple

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a problem with starting a Ruby On Rails application.

When I type

```
mtr start <application_name>
```

It will take a long time and fail with the following message:

```
Error Executing Command.
```

But the status of the application will show as "running", only that I will immediately get a HTTP 502 error when trying to access it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a faulty gem. Doing:

```
perl ~/check_gems.pl
```

Identified the culprit and after resintalling it worked fine.